# Local Storage with jQuery button Zoom

Tags: html, jquery, local-storage

I want Local Storage , I selected but now I want to add local Storage to it so it remembers when I leave the page

I made now this code but it doesn't seem to work properly, could someone please help me ?

- Local with button Zoom In , Zoom Out

```
HTML Button Zoom
```

```
<div class="me-4">
                <button id="zoom-out" class="btn btn-zoom" data-value="zoom-out"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i></button>
                <button id="zoom-in" class="btn btn-zoom" data-value="zoom-in"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
```

```
HTML Content
```

```
<section id="content" class="card card-body mt-2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Delectus maiores mollitia consequuntur? Cum
                commodi debitis et. Voluptates et provident, cum voluptate voluptatum alias, delectus asperiores atque
                magni, fugit eveniet laborum!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro blanditiis velit modi maxime quam, labore recusandae repellat tenetur unde in harum asperiores qui corporis vero ullam provident quisquam at voluptas laudantium expedita placeat ad? Corporis quod amet harum maiores omnis!</p>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur sequi velit laboriosam maxime
                nostrum necessitatibus aliquam iste reprehenderit numquam! Aliquid minus magni corporis magnam
                consequuntur minima sint beatae, sit voluptatum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis modi placeat incidunt at voluptatibus, quibusdam, perspiciatis eligendi obcaecati perferendis maiores animi, eum vel aspernatur doloremque fugit et quasi soluta beatae dolorum rem ducimus saepe! Ipsam adipisci modi quo, dignissimos facere accusamus omnis enim eaque sint perspiciatis quos vel tempore doloribus.</p>
        </section>
```

```
JS
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var getContent = $("#content");

    /* =============================== Local Storage =================================*/
    const savedZoom = localStorage.getItem('Zoom');

    if(savedZoom){
        $(getContent).css("fontSize", savedZoom);
    }
    
    /* =============================== BUTTON ZOOM =================================*/
    $(".btn-zoom").click(function(){
        var btnZoom = $(this).attr('data-value');
        console.log(btnZoom);

        $(".btn-zoom").each(function(){
            /* =============================== ZOOM OUT =================================*/
            if(btnZoom == "zoom-out"){
                var presentSize = getContent.css('fontSize');
                var latestSize = parseInt(presentSize.replace("px", "")) - 1;
                $(getContent).css("fontSize", latestSize + "px");
                // console.log(latestSize + "px");
            }
            /* =============================== ZOOM IN =================================*/
            if(btnZoom == "zoom-in"){
                var presentSize = getContent.css('fontSize');
                var latestSize = parseInt (presentSize.replace ("px", "")) + 1;
                $(getContent).css ("fontSize", latestSize + "px");
                // console.log(latestSize + "px");
            }
            saveZoom (btnZoom)
        })
    })

}
function saveZoom(btnZoom){
    localStorage.setItem("Zoom" , btnZoom)
}
```